# how to use $lookup in mongodb change stream?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

based on docs in [mongoDB Change Stream Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) i can use only these operations for getting output of change stream:

- $addFields
- $match
- $project
- $replaceRoot
- $replaceWith (Available starting in MongoDB 4.2)
- $redact
- $set (Available starting in MongoDB 4.2)
- $unset (Available starting in MongoDB 4.2)

but I want to use $lookup op :(

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Comment: If the docs explicitly state you can only these operators, that should mean you can only use these operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed operations are transformations on the change stream-produced documents. You are asking about joining other collections.

If you want to join other collections, you need to issue those queries separately from the change stream.

Comment: Is that good practice?

Comment: @MehdiKhlifi yes, it's good practice because it is the only way you can do it! If you use $match in your changestream watch then you've already narrowed things down. Manually looking up related info (as opposed to using $lookup) is an extra step, but it's still very efficient.